# Outdated tokens in use in message template

Tags: tokens, message-templates

I have the following message after upgrading Civicrm to 5.66

"Outdated tokens in use
You are using tokens that have been removed or deprecated.
Please review your event_offline_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$contributeMode} as it has been replaced by {no longer available / relevant}
Please review your event_offline_receipt message template and remove references to the token {$isAmountZero} as it has been replaced by {no longer available / relevant}"

In the template HTML format section I have;

```
  {if $contributeMode ne 'notify' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later and !$isOnWaitlist and !$isRequireApproval}
```

Should this be removed?

and...

```
   {if $contributeMode eq 'direct' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later and !$isOnWaitlist and !$isRequireApproval}
```

Should this be also removed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - those should be removed - they haven't been around for quite a while. We have quite a number of variables being deprecated in upcoming versions I'm afraid as we are replacing them with more manageable variables or tokens where possible. So you are probably best to do the minimum intervention for now

- ie
  (remove the reference to contributeMode, if you need to have the zero amount check then use `{if {contribution.total_amount|boolean}}` instead of `!isAmountZero`

and then when you get onto 5.68 plan to do a thorough update / recustomisation of your event offline template (which has more deprecations in 5.68, but should be fairly stable after that).

Also note you can delete rather than update the text versions of the template. If you do so a text version will be generated on the fly. Almost no-one or possibly absolutely no-one ever sees the text version

Comment: Do I remove the whole of the lines?
viz:
  {if $contributeMode ne 'notify' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later and !$isOnWaitlist and !$isRequireApproval}
...and...
       {if $contributeMode eq 'direct' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later and !$isOnWaitlist and !$isRequireApproval}

Also, if I wholly delete the text section. it will not be regenerated on the saving the page but "on the fly" means when I use the template. Is that correct?